# python get parsed arguments from CLI?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

Given an argument parser with `n` arguments, where I pass through the CLI only a subset, is there a clean way of extracting a dict/namespace of all the passed `k,v` arguments (even if they are identical to the default ones)?

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--a",type=str,default='a')
parser.add_argument("--b",type=str,default='b')
parser.add_argument("--c",type=str,default='c')
parser.add_argument("--d",type=str,default='d')
```

And

```
python run.py --a "e" --b "b"
```

I would like to have

```
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--a",type=str,default='a')
    parser.add_argument("--b",type=str,default='b')
    parser.add_argument("--c",type=str,default='c')
    parser.add_argument("--d",type=str,default='d')

    from_cli = parse_from_cli(parser) # from_cli = {'a':'e','b':'b'}
```

Comment: is "ns = parser.parse_args()" what you are looking for? This way you can access your arguments via "ns.a" or "ns['q']".

Comment: But this way, I won't have any option to distinguish between ns.c (default non-defined by the user), and ns.a,ns.b, defined by the user.

Comment: To start: I was wrong and you can only access them via ns.a.
Second: conceptually it shouldn't matter if it uses the default or not, you can just use the value you have. If you really want to know if they gave a value, you can test whether ns.a == 'a', but there is no way to distinguish between the default value or the user specifying the value --a=a himself.

Comment: Dries, I may fail to explain myself, but please don't tell me my use-case is useless:)
Given another namespace I'm loading, I wish to fuse the two settings, by taking the loaded namespace, with only the arguments I explicitly defined from the command line, discarding all others.